# I can not sort by city distance in GeoDjango (PostGis)

Tags: python, django, postgis, geodjango

The distance method does not work in GeoDjango (QuerySet)

My model :

```
class City(models.Model):

    name_english = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="city", db_index=True, related_name="city_relate")
    name_city_avito = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Country", db_index=True, related_name="Country_relate")
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Region", db_index=True, related_name="Region_relate")
    point = models.PointField(blank=True, null=True)
```

view.py

```
class Landing_head(View):

    def get(self, request):
        b = Site.objects.get_current()
        current_location = City.objects.get(site__id=b.id).point

        cities = City.objects.filter(point__distance_lte=(current_location, D(km=200))).distance(current_location).order_by('point_distance')[:1][0]

        for z in cities:
           print(z)
```

output error 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'distance'

Although it works in this version, without sorting by distance

```
class Landing_head(View):

    def get(self, request):
        b = Site.objects.get_current()
        current_location = City.objects.get(site__id=b.id).point

        cities = City.objects.filter(point__distance_lte=(current_location, D(km=200)))
        for z in cities:
            print(z)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django version >= 1.9 the `.distance` does not exist.

You need to annotate the distance measurement to your queryset and then order by the annotated field:

```
cities = City.objects.filter(
    point__distance_lte=(current_location, D(km=200))
).annotate(
    distance=Distance('point', current_location)
).order_by('distance')
```